# How to make payment success page as third tab of checkout process?

Tags: magento2

How to make payment confirmation page as third tab of checkout process?

I need to make checkout contain 3 tabs:

1 - shipping (1st image)

2 - payment (2nd image)

3 - confirmation (3d image)

So "checkout/onepage/success" (see at 3d image) should look like checkout step and become 3d tab like at 1st and 2nd images.

Of course need to show order number as it shown at current version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: @sivakumar I tried nothing. One thing I thought about - it's just to make design of "checkout/success" similar to shipping and payment and left all as is. But I assume that it is possible to extend checkout pages and don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general the thing is to do new checkout step as it shown on image.

It is possible with this manual http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_step.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can show the success page as a step without adding a custom step.

You can do this by copying the Magento_Checkout/template/progress-bar.html to your theme.

```
<ul class="opc-progress-bar">
      <!-- ko foreach: { data: steps().sort(sortItems), as: 'item' } -->
      <li class="opc-progress-bar-item" data-bind="css: item.isVisible() ? '_active' : ($parent.isProcessed(item) ? '_complete' : '')">
      <span data-bind="i18n: item.title, click: $parent.navigateTo"></span>
      </li>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <li class="opc-progress-bar-item">
          <span data-bind="i18n: 'Success'"></span>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

Also copy checkout_onepage_success.xml and add a block to show a fake stepNavigator.

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="checkout.progress.bar" template="BB_Checkout::progress-bar.phtml" 
 cacheable="false"/>
```

To add the fake stepNavigator you can add a progress-bar.phtml with the following content.

```
<ul class="opc-progress-bar">
<li class="opc-progress-bar-item _complete">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping'"></span>
</li>
<li class="opc-progress-bar-item _complete">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Review & Payments'"></span>
</li>
<li class="opc-progress-bar-item _active _complete">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Success'"></span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working solution.
Add  Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/progress-bar.html file in your theme
and add below code

```
 <ul class="opc-progress-bar">
    <!-- ko foreach: { data: steps().sort(sortItems), as: 'item' } -->
        <li class="opc-progress-bar-item" data-bind="css: item.isVisible() ? '_active' : ($parent.isProcessed(item) ? '_complete' : '')">
            <span data-bind="i18n: item.title, click: $parent.navigateTo"></span>
        </li>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <li class="opc-progress-bar-item">
          <span data-bind="i18n: 'Confirmation'"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Create checkout_onepage_success.xml in Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/ and add below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 @author Ashar Riaz
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
      <referenceContainer name="content">
             <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Success" name="custom.order.success" template="Magento_Checkout::progress-bar.phtml" before="-" >
             </block>
     </referenceContainer>    
 </body>
</page>
```

Now add custom phtml progressbar file 
create Vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/templates/progress-bar.phtml file and add below code

```
<ul class="opc-progress-bar opc-progress-bar-successpage">
    <li class="opc-progress-bar-item _complete">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Shipping'"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="opc-progress-bar-item _complete">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Review & Payments'"></span>
    </li>
    <li class="opc-progress-bar-item _active _complete">
        <span data-bind="i18n: 'Confirmation'"></span>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

Done !!

[image]